# google-cloud-sdkを動かしたい。

Tags: python, python3, google-cloud, python2

以下の環境なのですが、google-cloud-sdkを動かしたいです。

```
$ python -V
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.
$ conda -V
conda 4.6.8
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

ubuntuにpython2.7はプリインストールされているので、参照先をうまいことpython2.7に設定できれば動くかなと思ってとりあえずインストールしてみました。
インストールは通って、初期化も済んで、テスト的にbigqueryを使って見たところ以下が出てきました。

```
ERROR: Python 3 and later is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK. 
Please use Python version 2.7.x.
If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it 
by setting
the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.
```

ということで環境変数を以下のように設定してみました。

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/lib/python2.7
```

そうすると、以降どんなコマンドを打ってもpermission deniedと出るようになりました。

```
$ gcloud --version
/home/kyohei/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: 129: exec: 
/usr/lib/python2.7: Permission denied
```

こっからどうすれば良いのか、全く見当が尽きません。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[pyenv 環境で Google Cloud SDK をインストールする - Qiita](https://qiita.com/keisuke-nakata/items/0255104b7f807a0e499f)

を見たんですけど、pyenvを使わないとダメかな。
今のPythonのバージョンいくつですか？

`python -V` で3.6.8が出てしまうとだめだと思います。

Answer (score 0):

コメントありがとうございました。

pyenvをインストールするところで躓いてしまい、どうにもならなくなったので、ubuntu16.04を再インストールして対処しました。手順通りにやれば普通に使えるようになりました。

あと、自分の勘違いだったんですが、ubuntu18.04はpython2.7はインストールされていない(?)んですね。